# What is an efficient way to fix the issue that a[b] may return vector of different lengh?

Tags: r

```
> a <- factor(1:3)
> b <- c(0,1,2)
> ifelse(b == 0, 5, a[b])
[1] 5 2 1
```

I would expect to see `5,1,2`

The reason is that `a[b]` actually returns `1, 2`, which has different length from `a`, therefore the result of `ifelse` is corrupted due to recycling.

I can write `ifelse` with `if...else`, but it is highly inefficient. What is the common way to handle it?

Answer (score 3):

This solution yields the correct answer:

```
a <- factor(1:3)
b <- c(0,1,2)
a = as.numeric(a)
zero_logical = b != 0         # Precompute because if a contains a zero, this will also be replaced by 5
b[zero_logical] <- a[b[zero_logical]]
b[!zero_logical] <- 5
b
[1] 5 1 2
```

This solution uses two assignments, one for `b != 0` and one for `b == 0`, so this should be very fast in contrast to an explicit loop.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't compared the efficiency with Paul's answer, but for your consideration for this (perhaps) special case:

```
a <- factor(1:3)
b <- c(0,1,2)
a2 <- as.factor(c("5", a))
a2[b + 1]
# [1] 5 1 2
# Levels: 1 2 3 5
```

If you're looking for anything other than `b == 0`, this approach most likely won't work.

Comment: If `b` is never zero, doesn't the OP's original code work just fine?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I can't test it now, but I'm guessing that testing for a negative number in `b` would also pose a problem. But then this answer would also fail. ?

Comment: Yep, that's likely given how `[` handles a negative index :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
b[b == 0] <- NA
ifelse(is.na(b), 5, a[b])
```

Answer (score 0):

Both previous answers utilize the `a[_conditions_]` instead of `_conditions_(a[])` and that seems better for your case; this answer has the same concept too :).

A way -besides the others mentioned- is to use something like `a[ifelse(, , b)]` and not `ifelse(, , a[b])`. The only solution I could come up with was to enlarge `a` with a `5` at its end, so something like `a[ifelse(b == 0, which(a == 5), b)]` could be used; of course, `a` had to be re-assigned before the forementioned call.

Just to avoid changing `a` and avoid assigning extra variables (i.e. `a`'s backups) in the environments where you work, you can wrap everything inside a `local`; otherwise `local` is something that just looks cool in the answer and can be avoided:

```
a <- factor(1:3)
b <- c(0,1,2)

res <- local({  # just to keep all environments clean and to not re-assign `a`
a = as.numeric(as.character(a)) 
a[length(a) + 1] <- 5

a[ifelse(b == 0, which(a == 5), b)]
})
res
#[1] 5 1 2
a
#[1] 1 2 3   #not changed `a`
#Levels: 1 2 3
```

I can't think of a more elegant way to utilize the `a[ifelse(, , )]`. Also, I'm not sure if there are any constraints to this.

I hope I've not missed something serious.